Is there an example to a quaternary tree in mathematics?
As well known, a good example to a binary tree in mathematics is Stern-Brocot tree.
A good example to a ternary tree is Berggrens's tree of primitive Pythagorean triples.
I am not aware of other good examples to binary and ternary trees.
Is there an example to a quaternary tree in mathematics?

Take any binary tree and contract all the nodes at even depth

There's a wikipedia page specifically about quadtrees that lists several examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

I guess the question is "are there such trees naturally occurring in mathematics"?

@lisyarus Thank you. That is actually what I meant.
